# Only 2 of my 3 lists are presented in columns - 3rd list not there

Tags: python, python-3.x, string.format

I cannot figure out why only 2 of my 3 lists are being shown (trying to display all three of them in columns using zip)

```
    def columns(card_list = ()): 
        for line in zip(card_list[0],card_list[1],card_list[2]):
            print('{:30}{}'.format(*line))
```

[image: imgur link to what I get]

Comment: You should also fix the default value `def columns(card_list = ())` as it would cause an IndexError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last item in the list is being discarded by your format string. You should add a third placeholder for that:

```
print('{:30}{:30}{:30}'.format(*line))
#                 ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the third placeholder:

```
def columns(card_list = ()): 
for line in zip(card_list[0],card_list[1],card_list[2]):
    print('{:30}{:30}{:30}'.format(*line))
```